# Does this inequality hold $\operatorname{Trace}(A^TA) \ge \rho(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is an arbitrary square matrix and $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$. Does this inequality hold:
$$ \text{Trace}(A^{\top}A ) \ge \rho(A)?$$

Comment: If you scale $A$ by a factor $c>0$, the LHS is quadratic in $c$ while the RHS is linear in $c$. Therefore the inequality doesn't hold if the LHS is nonzero and $c$ is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user1551 explained, a suitable counterexample could be
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} c & 0 \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $c \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$.
Then, we have
$$
\text{Tr}(A^T A)
= \text{Tr} \begin{pmatrix} 2 c^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
= 2c^2 < 
c
= \rho(A).
$$